# VirtualBox guest freezes host when writing to host drive

Tags: virtualbox, 19.04

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04 and I'm getting total system lockups running VirtualBox when the guest writes to the host drive.

The only error I see in the journal is numerous sets of lines like this:

```
  VBoxNetFlt: Failed to segment a packet (-22)
```

But there are instances of this prior to the lockup that seem to be benign.